# iCheck jQuery blocks custom script

Tags: jquery, onclick, icheck

I used "iCheck jQuery" to modificate the style of the checkbox. But when i add a  iCheck script - my onlick metod stops working. Why it happening?

```
<input id="my_cb"  type="checkbox" value="yes_n" onclick="hide_row_metod()"/>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#my_cb').iCheck({
        checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_square-blue',
        radioClass: 'iradio_square-blue',
        increaseArea: '20%' // optional
      });
    });    
    </script>
```

My script:

```
<script>
   function hide_row_metod() {
     if(document.getElementById('my_cb').checked){
        document.getElementById('row1').style.display = "none";
     }else{
            document.getElementById('row1').style.display = "inline";
          }
     }
</script>
```

Comment: Inspect the rendered HTML once iCheck get applied

Answer (score 26, accepted):

[`iCheck`](https://github.com/fronteed/iCheck) registers custom events you can listen for. I put up a [working example on jsbin](http://jsbin.com/sahojajice/3/), the main difference is this:

```
$("#my_cb").on("ifChanged", hide_row_metod);
```

There are two events: [`ifChecked` and `ifUnchecked`](https://github.com/fronteed/iCheck#callbacks). If you want to catch all changes to your checkbox, you need to either listen for both or simply listen for `ifChanged`. This will work to toggle the row, as you are testing for `checked` in your `hide_row_metod`.

In my example, I use a block element `div#row1`, so it will render differently (`inline`) after checking and unchecking.

Also: you got a typo in your method name (missing `h`).

Answer (score 3):

I know it's been some time since this question has been asked. I've made a script to capture onclick attribute from each radio / checkbox and attach it to its corresponding iCheck / iRadio. Just remember to run it AFTER iCheck has been applied. Set a timeout or run it after iCheck's implementation:

```
$("[class*='icheckbox'],[class*='iradio']").each(function(){
  $(this).find("ins").attr("onclick", $(this).find("input").attr("onclick"));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It is probably overridden by the `iCheck` script. Try using only jQuery:

```
$('#my_cb').on('click', function() {
    $('#row1').css('display', this.checked ? 'none' : 'inline');
});
```